Arduino Uno R4 can only produce certain PWM duty cycles
I'm using the servo library on an Arduino Uno R4 to control a servo. However, when I use Servo.microSeconds(), the duty cycle only changes with every 100th microsecond, i.e. a an input of 1600-1699 produces one duty cycle, and then 1700-1799 produces another, which means the servo can only move with steps of about 13 degrees. I get the same result no matter which pin I use. Using Servo.write() also gives the same result.
Is this a hardware fault? Has anyone experienced something like this? The fact that it's exactly every 100 microseconds would lead me to believe it was by design, but I can't find any mention of the servo library working like this in the documentation.
I tested the sketch on an off-brand Arduino Uno I found, and the duty cycle increased linearly as intended. So I guess it's just my Arduino that had a fault, or maybe it's a peculiarity of the Arduino Uno R4?

This user of the Arduino forums also seems to have experienced a similar, if not the same, issue at you have, see Trouble with Servos on R4 Wifi. There is already a bug on Github, PWM duty cycle range not continuous on UNO R4 #113, which was closed as completed on Jan 9 2024. So, may be you have an out of date library?
On the Arduino Uno R4 compatability page, under Tested and Confirmed Libraries, as of the time of writing, the Servo libraries is being listed as compatible:



Also note that they was another Servo library bug, Release update that fixes servo jitter issue on R4 #128, that was fixed a week ago (July 4 2024). Maybe it was this latter bug that you experienced (although, tbh, it doesn't sound to be the same issue, whereas the former bug does) and perhaps this later fix has now resolved your issue

The issue you're experiencing is likely due to the specific implementation or limitations of the Servo library on the Arduino Uno R4. Try updating the Servo library, checking for conflicts in your code, or directly controlling the PWM signal to achieve finer control. If the problem persists, consider using an external servo controller for more precise control.
